# Can I buy Xbox Live games via PC and transfer them on a flash drive to a Xbox 360 internal HDD?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Due to the region restriction I cannot access Xbox Live on my Xbox, even if I purchased a Gold membership. However it seems that I can purchase games from Xbox Live Marketplace on a PC. I assume this means I can then download them on the PC, and I would like to know if I can transfer them through a flash drive to the 250GB internal HDD of my Xbox 360 console, and then run them from the HDD.

Comment: How are you downloading the games to your PC? Where are you based?

Comment: I never tried, but it seems that as long as I was asked for the credit card details, I may be able to buy a game or download a free demo on the PC HDD or on a flash drive connected to it. Then I will try to play the game from the flash drive or transfer it from the stick to the HDD of the 360 console. The region I am in is Romania. It's at least strange, as long as the XBOX consoles are officially sold in this market.

Comment: I can't speak to other regions, but I don't believe downloading them to a PC is ever an option. Also, the portion of a USB drive formatted for the Xbox isn't accessible to browse or copy data to on a PC without likely something that isn't quite legal.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you were thinking. I've edited that guess into the question to make it clearer what your situation is.

Answer (score 5):

You have the option of purchasing games for download to an xbox with your profile on it, however, you can **NOT** download xbox games to the PC and then transfer to your xbox.

Quite the opening for piracy if you could.

I speak from experience in purchasing games online. After buying ANY non-avatar item in the Marketplace you will be presented with a notification stating that your item will be downloaded to your 360 and will appear in your My Games list after it has been downloaded.

It is also entirely possible that [the full Xbox Live (Marketplace et al.) is not available in Romania](http://www.xbox.com/ro-ro/). While it may be a market for Xboxes to exist, governmental issues may be blocking access. If you wish to attempt to play on Xbox Live, Try finding a proxy to run through, I can't go further into detail as I've never had to look that information up. I also don't know international law or the conflicts invited therein.

Source:
[image: Purchase of DLC for Might and Magic (Free Game of October 1-14) made message]

Comment: +1! Would be improved 1000% with a freehand circle though.[/deadpan]

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You mean a circle on the image?

Comment: Around the "Your items will appear in…" part, yes. Arqade has many freehand circle connoisseurs among its users who would approve. (It's a bit of a meme / in-joke.) Also, it would just nicely highlight the relevant part of the image.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Done.

Comment: Not bad, not bad. Not actual freehand, but good line weight, colour saturation, and an pleasing amount of aliasing. ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ALL THE MSPAINTS!